# Transform a comma separated list of numbers in one data.frame column to a new list in a new column

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a data.frame in which one of the columns is a list of numbers, separated by commas, with a variable length. Here is a simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(ids=c('1','2','3'), coords=c('1,2,3', '4,4,4,4', '9,8,7,6,5'))
ids   coords
1     1,2,3
2     4,4,4,4
3     9,8,7,6,5
```

I want to create a new columns that is a list of numbers that are a function of the numbers in the coords column. For instance, the function x+10:

```
ids   coords     coordsf
1     1,2,3      11,12,13
2     4,4,4,4    14,14,14,14
3     9,8,7,6,5  19,18,17,16,15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub`

```
df$coordsf <- sub(',','',gsub('^|,', ',1',df$coords))
df$coordsf
#[1] "11,12,13"       "14,14,14,14"    "19,18,17,16,15"
```

Or

```
gsub("(,|^)(?=\\d)", "\\11", df$coords, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "11,12,13"       "14,14,14,14"    "19,18,17,16,15"
```

---

Or if we need to add 10

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$coords), ","), 
      function(x) paste(as.numeric(x)+10,collapse=",") )
#[1] "11,12,13"       "14,14,14,14"    "19,18,17,16,15"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the function to be a mathematical function. For instance, something like ((800-x)/800*2)-1.

Comment: @YBA The column is a `factor`.  You cannot apply a mathematical function on a `factor/character` column.

Comment: Of course, that's a part of the problem. I read this from a tab-delimited data file. I am sure it is possible in R to separate to a vector of strings, convert each string to integer, compute the function, and then create the new string from the new vector.

Comment: @YBA Anyway, I got the expected output as showed in your post.  There are many ways to solve a problem.

Comment: @YBA  In your post, it is mentioned about `x+10`.  I updated the post.

Comment: Great, the last suggestion is exactly what I needed. Thanks